# Group_Concat() from same DB

Tags: mysql

i'm doing a query on DB that i want return to me the group concat of the duplicate category for example in this table

[image]

I want the result of the concats parent from the same table in MySQL as this way

[image]

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: do you want the other parents for the platform id, or for the name, or for where both name and platform id match?  whatever it is, you need to join your table to itself and group by the id of your from table and just use group_concat on the parent name of the joined table.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please test this:

```
CREATE TABLE Monopoly (Id INT,Name VARCHAR(30),Platform_ID INT,Parent_Name VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO Monopoly VALUES
(1, 'Rosatis', 1113080,'Rosatis Franchase'),
(2, 'Rosatis', 1113080,'Rosatis Global'),
(3, 'Rosatis', 1113080,'Rosatis USA'),
(4, 'Macianos Food', 1125676,'Rosatis Franchase'),
(5, 'Macianos Food', 1125676,'Rosatis Global'),
(6, 'Aurora BAR', 1452355,'Bar Grill Global'),
(7, 'Aurora BAR', 1452355,'USA Group'),
(8, 'Aurora BAR', 1452355,'Food Group');
```

Full Code:

```
SELECT M1.Id,M1.Name,M1.Platform_ID,M1.Parent_Name,Family_Name
FROM Monopoly M1
JOIN (SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Parent_Name) AS Family_Name FROM Monopoly GROUP BY Name) AS M2 ON M1.Name = M2.Name
GROUP BY Id,Name,Platform_ID,Parent_Name;
```

If we test the code:

[image: XXX]